Как показать длительность времени в PG?
Задание: выбрать из таблицы колонку "Миллисекунды" и преобразовать ее в длительность в формат "минуты: секунды". Например, "33000" --> "00:33". Как это сделать?

С чем возникли проблемы, с минутами или секундами? Добавьте пример кода.

@Anaconda, RTFM - прочти наконец документацию.

-- Создание таблицы Время
CREATE TABLE Время
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Миллисекунды BIGSERIAL,
    Секунды SMALLSERIAL,
    Минуты SMALLSERIAL,
    Часы SMALLSERIAL
);

-- Добавление новых записей в таблицу Время
INSERT INTO
Время (id, Миллисекунды, Секунды, Минуты, Часы)

VALUES (1, 33000, 10, 20, 20),
(2, 34000, 20, 30, 21),
(3, 35000, 30, 40, 22),
(4, 120000, 40, 50, 23),
(5, 5550000, 50, 59, 24);

-- Вывод таблицы Время для наглядносити
SELECT *
FROM Время;

-- Преобразование миллисекунд в формат минуты:секунды
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(Миллисекунды / 1000), 'MI:SS') AS Форматированное_время FROM Время;



для значения 5550000 точно будет 32 минуты? как по мне должно показать 92:30 , такой кейс не учтен
